# Bootstrap fixed width table columns in container fluid

Tags: html, django, html-table, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I have a question for you. I'm trying to fix the size of my table colum in a **container fluid** div. I have tried to set **`style="width: xx.x%"`** but it continues to change based on the cell content.

I have also tried with max-with, but it continues to do not work. Below my code:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                  <table class="table table-sm text-nowrap">
            <thead>
              <tr class="bg-info text-white">
                <th style="max-width: 1%">2020</th>
                <th style="max-width: 9%">Voci</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="max-width: 7.5%">Gen</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="max-width: 7.5%">Feb</th>
.......
```

I want that the column have a fixed width (ad example max and min equal to 7.5%). 
How could I get this in bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `d-flex` property for your `table` in order to make `fix width`.

You can play with `col` class to specify width for each column.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <table id="productSizes" class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr class="bg-info d-flex">
              <th class="col-3">2020</th>
              <th class="col-3">Voice</th>
              <th class="col-3">Gen</th>
              <th class="col-3">Feb</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="d-flex">
              <td class="col-3">First Column with fixed width look at that, it is moving text to next line if it
                overflowing</td>
              <td class="col-3">Second Column with fixed width</td>
              <td class="col-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, atque earum
                asperiores ex
                quod quia mollitia dese</td>
              <td class="col-3">This is third clumn</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="d-flex">
              <td class="col-3">8</td>
              <td class="col-3">84 - 86</td>
              <td class="col-3">66 - 68</td>
              <td class="col-3">94 - 96</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: does not works for me. Becouse I have more than 12 columns and col-3 overflow the gird

Comment: Well then you have to provide the complete code on which you are working on.